# docker-compose: open port in container but not bind it from host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

(**Note**: the whole problem is because I misread the IP address of the docker network. The `my-network` is `172.22.0.0/16` instead of `127.22.0.0/16`. I slightly modified the OP to reflect the original problem I encountered)

I created a service (a small web server) using `docker-compose`. The network part is defined as

```
services:
  service:
    image: ... (this image uses port 9000)
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
networks:
  default:
    name: my-network
```

After `docker-compose up`, I observe:

- the host gets an IP address `172.22.0.1` and the client gets `172.22.0.2`.
- I can successfully ping the client from the host `ping 127.22.0.2`.
- From the host machine: the web server can be reached using

  - `127.22.0.1:9000`
  - `127.22.0.2:9000`
  - `localhost:9000`
  - `192.168.0.10:9000` (This is the host's IP address in the LAN)

Now I want to restrict the access from the host using `172.22.0.2:9000` only. I feel this should be possible if I don't bind the container's 9000 port to the host's 9000 port. Then I deleted the `ports: 9000:9000` part from the `docker-compose.yml`. Now I observe:

- All the above four methods do not work now, including `127.22.0.2:9000`
- The client can still be pinged from the host using `127.22.0.2`

I think: since the the host and the container are both in a bridge network `my-network` and have obtained their IP addresses. The web server should still be reachable from `127.22.0.2:9000`. But this is not the case.

My questions:

- why does it work like this? Shouldn't the host/container in the same subnet `127.22.0.0/16` be able to talk to each other freely?
- How to achieve what I want: do not forward port 9000 from host to container and only allow accessing the container using its subnet IP address.

Comment: Hosts within the same network can access each other by the service name. or, `docker.host.internal`
p.s i dont see your client in the compose file, and therefore, it wont be on the same network.

Comment: @Dementic, I don't have a second container as the client to communicate with this container. What I want is to use the docker host (the host ran this docker container) as the client. Aren't they both in this subnet `127.22.0.0/16` and should be able  to talk to each other without publishing the port `9000:9000`

Comment: No, The service runs on its own network  (my-network), while your other service is running on your local PC's network. as i mentioned, you should still be able to access it using the docker resolver, `docker.host.internal:9000` from your network.

Comment: @Dementic my-network has subnet mask 127.22.0.0/16. I don't have "other serives". Only these two component: a local PC and the container. They are both in subnet 127.22.0.0/16. If you check `ifconfig` in local PC, you can find the `127.22.0.1` IP address. Moreover, `docker inpect network my-network` shows that `127.22.0.1` is the gateway of the network. And the local pc can ping the container using `127.22.0.2`. Why can't it access the port `127.22.0.2:9000`

Comment: On my PC accessing '172.17.0.2:8080' even without port binding is working (when I run a container which listens on port 8080). My guess is that you are using none standart subnet '127.22.0.0/16' which is causing this issue. Note that '127.0.0.0/8' address space is reserved to host. See: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses . 
So I guess @acran post is the answer

Comment: @ofirule I didn't put any explicit config for the `my-network` other than the above. I inspected the network by `docker inspect network my-network`, the output in `IPAM.Config` tells me the subnet is `172.22.0.0/16`

Comment: @ofirule what does this mean in your post: `when I run a container which listens on port 8080`. Does it mean you used `-p 8080:8080`? As in the OP, adding this will make all of them work. What I want is to make them work without this binding and access them using the subnet IP.

Comment: No I ran it without adding the flag `-p 8080:8080`. I was able to achieve exactly what you described., accessing my server only via '172.17.0.2:8080'. There is a small chance it's related to the docker version. This is my version `20.10.12, build e91ed57`
Also there is a chance you container have some special network handling

Comment: @ofirule I confirmed what you said after fixing the typo as mentioned by acran. His answer is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the networking is correct. Removing the port binding from the `docker-compose.yml` will remove the exposed port from the host. Since the host is also part of the virtual network `my-network` with an IP in the same subnet as the container, your service should be reachable from the host using the container IP directly.

But I think, this is actually a simple typo and instead of

```
127.22.0.0/16
```

you actually have

```
172.22.0.0/16
```

as the subnet for `my-network`! This is a typical subnet used by `docker` in the default configuration, while [`127.0.0.0/8` is always bound to the loopback device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#Name_resolution)!

So connecting to `127.22.0.2` will actually connect you to `localhost` - which is consistent with the symptoms you encountered:

- connecting to `127.22.0.2:9000` will work only if the port is exposed on the host
- you can always pint `127.22.0.2` since it is the loopback address

Comment: Do you mean that when I pinged `127.22.0.2`, I was actually pinging my host instead of the container?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Comment: Now I confirm that the service can be reached from 172.22.0.2:9000 after removing the port binding. The typo indeed introduced another scenario. With the port binding, both 172.22.0.2:9000 and 127.22.0.2:9000 work. As exaplained by this answer.